# keras load_model not work in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I tried load model that i created in my local machine,so first i upload my model(.h5) in to google drive and then i access my model in colab using following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then i tried with following code

```
from keras.models import load_model
classifier = load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/face_shape_recog_model.h5')
```

after run above code i got following error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

i tried with uninstall and install tensorflow and keras but still face the same issue
and also i tried with solutions mentioned in [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9501)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to an incompatiblity between keras 2.2 and tensorflow 2.x. You should be able to fix the issue by updating to keras 2.3 or newer:

```
!pip install -U keras
```

*Edit 2020-04-10: it looks like Keras 2.3 is now the default in Colab, so the above fix is no longer necessary.*